# Change Ruby exception class to prepend text to original exception message

Tags: ruby, exception

There is an original exception class that is a subclass of `StandardError` and its exceptions are thrown as `raise RequiredArgumentMissingError 'message'`. In my application, I need to change this class so that its exceptions are shown to the user as `ERROR: message`. How do I change the original exception class to prepend my part of message to it?

Original exception class:

```
class Thor
  class RequiredArgumentMissingError < StandardError
  end
end
```

My app:

```
class CLI < Thor
  class RequiredArgumentMissingError
    # I need to prepend 'ERROR: ' to the original exception message here
  end
end
```

**EDIT** I don't explicitly raise `RequiredArgumentMissingError` in my app, it's raised by other classes/methods in `Thor` class. So I can't actually subclass from it but I need to keep the original class name but change the implementation. Is that possible at all?

Comment: If you do a `raise RequiredArgumentMissingError, "message"` `, you get "RequiredArgumentMissingError: message" as a message.

Comment: Are you sure `raise 'message'` raises that exception class? http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-raise says raising a string always raises a RuntimeError.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that even if CLI is a subclass of Thor, `CLI::RequiredArgumentMissingError != Thor::RequiredArgumentMissingError` if you define the inner class inside CLI again. Original methods in the Thor class will raise the `Thor::RequiredArgumentMissingError` class. So you want to redefine this class. The easiest way to achieve what you want is to define the initialize method.

```
class Thor
    class RequiredArgumentMissingError
         def initialize str
             super("ERROR: "+str)
         end
    end
end
```

in the case the initialize was already defined and is complicated, you can alias and call the original initialize method from your overwritten one like this:

```
class Thor
    class RequiredArgumentMissingError
        alias :orig_initialize :initialize
        def initialize msg
            orig_initialize("ERROR: "+msg)
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Why would I redefine RuntimeError when I should redefine RequiredArgumentMissingError?

Comment: Then I misunderstood your question - as you pointed out, `raise "text"` always raises RuntimeError. You can of course do the same in any subclass of `Exception`.
But if the RequiredArgumentMissingError is your class, you can of course do it cleaner without the alias.

Comment: Sorry, that was my mistake, I edited the original post. I raise RequiredArgumentMissingError. And RequiredArgumentMissingError is not my class but a class of the thor gem so I can only redefine it, not subclass.

Comment: I did not notice your edit and did not notice you accepted the answer before I completely changed it to match your question. But it should still solve the issue, the easier way.